# Form not working on Mobile Device

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a website called diditdrop.com. Within the website there is a form where the user enters a number and then submits the number. On the desktop version of the site, the form works great. On the mobile version, the form is not responsive (i.e. i tap on the screen and nothing focuses or pops up. Additionally, the button underneath it doesn't work either).

I'm not sure what to do. I've been stuck on it for a few hours now. I've pasted a snippet of my code below, however, it doesn't look too strange. If someone could take a look at my site, and then recommend a better way of implementing, I would sincerely appreciate it.

```
<form class = "form-inline" action="https://formspree.io/x@gmail.com" method="POST">
  <div class= "form-group">
        <span>
           <input type="tel" id = "form1" placeholder="digits here" tabindex="1" class="boxed form-control" name="number"/><br>
        </span>
        <span>
           <input type="submit" id = "buttonmove"  class="btn boxed" value="get dat new new"name="number" />
        </span>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure what to do. Explain your problem or this should be closed as offtopic

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I apologize for being so vague. I've updated the post and would love some of your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code it will work:

add the style="float:left" to the image like below

```
<div id="pictureface" class="col-lg-6">
          <img style="float:left" class="img-responsive" src="http://static.stereogum.com/uploads/2016/09/CtUYD4uWYAIB1MH-1475280486.jpg">
        </div>
```